# Problem with position of "might/possible" in the sentence

Tags: idioms, conditional-constructions

Are both the sentences correct ?  (Context: I have recently bought the car.)

> That might make me get to my work on time.
>
> That makes it possible for me to get my work on time.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, but neither is how a native speaker would say it.

In both sentences, "get to my work on time" would normally just be "get to work on time".  The second sentence is pretty good, other than that.

In your first sentence, "make me" implies that it is forcing or requiring you to do it. You might use that sentence if you have a habit of being late and your boss threatened to dock your pay.